# How can I inject ServletContext in Spring unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, servlets, junit

I need to write a jUnit test for a rather complex application which runs in a Tomcat.

I wrote a class which builds up my Spring context.

```
private static ApplicationContext
springContext = null;

springContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                     new String[] {"beans"....});
```

In the application there is a call:

```
public class myClass implements ServletContextAware { 

.... final String folder = **servletContext.getRealPath**("/example"); ...
}
```

which breaks everything, because the `ServletContext` is null.

I have started to build a mock object:

```
static ServletConfig servletConfigMock = createMock(ServletConfig.class);
static ServletContext servletContextMock = createMock(ServletContext.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        expect(servletConfigMock.getServletContext())
                 .andReturn(servletContextMock).anyTimes();

        expect(servletContextMock.getRealPath("/example"))
                 .andReturn("...fulllpath").anyTimes();
        replay(servletConfigMock);
        replay(servletContextMock);
    }
```

Is there a simple method to inject the `ServletContext` or to start the Tomcat with a deployment descriptor at the runtime of the jUnit test?

I am using: Spring, Maven, Tomcat 6 and EasyMock for the mock objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want is to test the web-layer.
There are a couple of ways to do it:

- use [`MockServletContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html) provided by spring. This is the best way - check the linked documentation for how to do it.
- use [ServletUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html) from HtmlUnit
- use the [cactus framework](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/)
- use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to test the web layer functionally
- make a runtime mock as you did

And whenever you want to inject something in a test, use [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)

The complication comes from the fact that the web-layer is not quite suitable for unit-testing. It is more a subject of functional testing.

If there are methods that seem suitable for unit-testing, they perhaps belong to the service layer. And they should not have a dependency on the `ServletContext`

Comment: The mail goal is to save time: after each change, I would have to run maven and then start tomcat. It would have been nice if I could use the junit test to check - in my case a webservice, which has many dependencies - the functionality of the methode... basicly I want to wait less for each functiontest. I will look into ReflectionTestUtils. It seems promising. Thx for the hint.